# RF inert adhesive for building antennas in the UHF to low GHz region

Tags: antenna-construction, uhf, microwave

I want to experiment with different mechanical designs for some Yagi antennas for 440 MHz through perhaps 2.3 GHz. I am looking for some adhesives and/or potting-like materials that would be relatively RF-inert at those frequencies. Can anyone make a suggestion for a material?

Comment: For what application? A little dab to secure an element in a boom? Or to encapsulate the entire antenna?

Comment: what does "RF-inert" mean to you? Low loss (low $\tan \delta$)? dielectric properties as close as possible to air (low $\epsilon$)? Magnetic properties as close as possible to metal ($\mu_r$)?

Comment: This would be to secure, say, a matching network to a boom. I would like the material of the adhesive to NOT create any significant detuning effects or similar to the original design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Epic Resins](http://www.epicresins.com/ElectronicsPotting/RFdevices). They have epoxies and potting compounds that are characterized into the GHz range. [Master Bond](https://www.masterbond.com/industries/adhesives-microwave-and-rf-applications) is another possible source.

Do be aware that when assembling antennas using epoxy, that it can act as a dielectric material. This can affect the primary design parameters of the antenna.